# iOS using External Object in Nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am writing an application that needs to interfaces with different backend systems. I decided to use a Protocol in order to abstract my backend Classes. I created a nib called LoginViewController that contains an "External Object" reference of type "NSObject", and wired it to the systemDelegate outlet in my LoginViewController.

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *captchaImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *captchaTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSObject <BackEndSystemDelegate> *systemDelegate;

- (IBAction) submitCaptcha:(id) sender;
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard: (id)sender;
- (IBAction) animateViewUp: (id) sender;
- (IBAction) animateViewDown: (id) sender;
- (void) animateViewOnYAxis: (int) offset;
- (void) loadCaptchaImage;

@end
```

I instanciate the LoginViewController in my application delegate, then try to load the nib with the external object reference. My code calls the `loadNibNamed` and crashes without a stack trace. I do not reach the NSLog statements after the invocation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    NSObject <BackEndSystemDelegate> *systemDelegate = [[ACMEBackEndSystemDelegate alloc] init];


    // Init LoginView, and load nib with systemDelegate
    self.viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *proxies = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:systemDelegate forKey:@"systemDelegate"];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:proxies forKey:UINibExternalObjects];

    NSArray *toplevelobjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginViewController" 
                                                             owner:self.viewController 
                                                           options:options];

    if (toplevelobjects) {
        NSLog(@"toplevelobjects is nil");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"toplevelobjects count %d", [toplevelobjects count]);
    }


    NSLog(@"Controller: %@, View: %@", viewController, viewController.view);

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I am at a loss trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
J Garcia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments:

- Generally you refer to a delegate object using the pattern `id<SomeProtocolName>` and not `NSObject<SomeProtocolName>`
- You `alloc` your `systemDelegate` variable but never `release` it. This is a memory leak.
- If the `ACMEBackEndSystemDelegate` class implements the `BackEndSystemDelegate` protocol, it is sufficient to allocate it like `ACMEBackEndSystemDelegate* systemDelegate = [[ACMEBackEndSystemDelegate alloc] init];`

Now, as for your crash, you said there's a crash on this line:

```
NSArray *toplevelobjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginViewController" 
                                                             owner:self.viewController 
                                                           options:options];
```

I assume you have a .xib called `LoginViewController.xib`. Open it up. That is the class type set for "File's Owner"? Is it `LoginViewController`? If not, set it. Now check the `view` outlet property. Is it set to a `UIView` in the .xib (perhaps a top-level `UIView` object)? If not, set it.

Comment: I followed your advice by adding the autorelease to ACMEBackEndSystemDelegate, verifying all the wires, and confirming the file owner is LoginViewController. The app still crashes. I noticed that it loads, if I remove the "External Object" from the nib. Re-adding and wiring causes the same problem.

Comment: The problem is that "External Object". You are using it as a way for the `LoginViewController` to know about a `BackEndSystemDelegate`? Just use a `@property` instead; create your `BackEndSystemDelegate` in your app delegate (as you are now), and then just set the property when you initialize your `LoginViewController`. I've never had a reason to use "External Objects" in iOS applications yet.

Comment: You make a good point. I was using an External Object, since the LoginViewController was calling a delegate method on viewDidLoad. I made the delegate a property as suggested, and called the delegate method after the view controller was instantiated. I guess I was making the problem harder than it need to be. Thanks a bunch for the assistance.